# sms intent not working titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile

I my code for sms intent does not give any responses..nor message dialogbox appears..iam stuck in this for days..please help

Here is the code:

```
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action : Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEWs,
        type : "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"
    });
    intent.putExtra("address", "111111111");
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Body of Message");
    try {
        Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Ti.UI.createNotification({
            message : "Error"
        }).show();
    }
```

should i add anything in the intent filters?plz need some advice.. i do noticed that intents were not working in this titanium sdk version 3.4.1..is there any fix?

Comment: Plz do comment if this if some more information is needed...